# Cypress get element length returns double

Tags: cypress

I am trying to test the insertion of an item and check the length of the items found before and after the addition operation. Here is the element

```
<metadata class="chartbase" issubtitle="false" iscontent="true" graphictype="icon" name="barSimpleRectangle">
<metadata class="chartitem" index="0" name="" value="25"></metadata>
<metadata class="chartitem" index="1" name="" value="30"></metadata>
<metadata class="chartitem" name="" index="2" value="36"></metadata>
```

I try to get the chartitems before the addition, increment it by 1 and then call the addition which inserts an chartitem. Now i compare the size with the earlier size using the said code

```
cy.get('.chartitem').its('length').then((size)=>{        
    cy.log("chart items length is ",size);
    size++;
    cy.log("totalChartItems is ",size);
    cy.get('.insertNewChartItem').eq(0).click({force:true});
    cy.wait(2000);
    cy.get('.chartitem').its('length').then((newsize)=>{
        cy.log("new chart items length is ",newsize);
    })
})
```

size returned here is 3, But newsize returns me 8. Is this a cypress bug?

Comment: Tried this variation: ```cy.get('.input').its('length').then((size)=>{
      cy.log(`input items length is ${size}`);
      cy.contains('Add')
        .click()
      cy.contains('Add')
        .click()
      cy.contains('Add')
        .click()
      cy.get('input').its('length').then((newsize)=>{
        cy.log(`new input items length is ${newsize}`);
      })```

It starts with 1 input, then adds 3, the first length sees 1 input, the second length sees 4 inputs. So that behaviour is correct. Seems that you application actually has more chart items than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot repro. Are you sure there isn't a bug in your item insertion? Also, I'm not sure why you're manually incrementing the size (what's the difference between `items length` and `totalChartItems`?).

```js
cy.document().then( doc => {
    doc.body.innerHTML = `
        <metadata class="chartbase" issubtitle="false" iscontent="true" graphictype="icon" name="barSimpleRectangle">
        <metadata class="chartitem" index="0" name="" value="25"></metadata>
        <metadata class="chartitem" index="1" name="" value="30"></metadata>
        <metadata class="chartitem" name="" index="2" value="36"></metadata>
    `;
});
cy.get(`.chartitem`).its(`length`).then((size) => {
    expect(size).to.eq(3);
    cy.document().then( doc => {
        doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML +
            `<metadata class="chartitem" name="" index="3" value="37"></metadata>`;
    });
    cy.get(`.chartitem`).its(`length`).then((newsize) => {
        expect(newsize).to.eq(4);
    });
});
```